# Retornar todos os parâmetros do constructor de uma função em Javascript

Tags: javascript, funções

Imaginem a seguinte situação:

Tenho diversas "classes" construídas a partir de funções javascript onde as propriedades delas são definidas dentro do constructor. Assim:

```js
var Pessoa = function(data) {
    this.nome     = arguments[0].nome     || '';
    this.telefone = arguments[0].telefone || '';
    ... // n parâmetros ...
    this.email    = arguments[0].email    || '';
};
```

O uso da propriedade `arguments[0]` é usado para que seja enviado um objeto com todas as propriedades que serão definidas para essa classe Pessoa. Existe alguma forma de eu retornar todas as propriedades que eu tenho dentro do constructor dessa `classe`?

Até onde eu entendo de Javascript, provavelmente não conseguiria fazer isso nativamente. Sendo assim, utilizando uma função prototipada, como posso retornar todos os parâmetros definidos dentro do meu construtor?

Answer (score 0):

Bem pelo que percebi voce quer retornar todos os parametros definidos no construtor, so nao percebi bem de onde o objeto `arguments` vem.

Podemos retornar os parametros defenidos na 'classe' `Pessoa` da seguinte forma:

Digamos que a classe ja esta declarada.

```
var pessoa = new Pessoa(data); // instanciamos a classe

for(param in pessoa){ // aplicamos um loop
    console.log(param) // aqui serao retornados todos os parametros defenidos de Pessoa
    console.log(pessoa[param]) // aqui serao retornados os valores
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para saberes que propriedades uma intância tem podes fazer assim:

```js
var Pessoa = function(data) {
    this.nome     = arguments[0].nome     || '';
    this.telefone = arguments[0].telefone || '';
    // ... n parâmetros ...
    this.email    = arguments[0].email    || '';
};

var sergio = new Pessoa({nome: 'sergio', telefone: '1234', email: 'foo@bar.com'});
console.log(Object.keys(sergio));
```

Isto funciona para "classes" hà moda antiga mas também para classes modernas:

```js
class Pessoa {
  constructor() {
    this.nome = arguments[0].nome || '';
    this.telefone = arguments[0].telefone || '';
    // ... n parâmetros ...
    this.email = arguments[0].email || '';
  }
};

var sergio = new Pessoa({
  nome: 'sergio',
  telefone: '1234',
  email: 'foo@bar.com'
});
console.log(Object.keys(sergio));
```

Penso ser isso que estavas à procura. Se o que procuras são as propriedades que são defenidas no momento de instanciação do objeto, isso é mais complexo, terias de usar getters e setters com algum tipo de memória que possam indicar quando foram setados.